# I want make list with django

Tags: django

```
category1 = ''
category1_tmp = ['a','b',c','d']
for n in category1_tmp:
    category1 &= n + '|'
```

django error : unsupported operand type(s) for &=: 'str' and 'str'

what i want : a|b|c|d

how can I solve?

Comment: What is `query1 &= n + '|'` supposed to do?

Comment: I want to save in my db like that.
no list.

Comment: But the `&=` makes no sense. `category1` is a *string*, hence `category1 &= ...` is not defined.

Comment: Umm. Can you tell me more?

Comment: exactly what is the expected output?

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the elements together with:

```
category1 = '|'.join(category1_tmp)
```

For a list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` this will result in `category1 = 'a|b|c|d'`.